# How to go from integral with $\theta((k^+)^2 - \vec{l}_\epsilon^2 - \vec{k}_\perp^2)$ to $\theta(k^+ - |\vec{k}_\perp|)$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, divergent-integrals

I am trying to reproduce the calculation of the so called collinear-soft function, defined in arxiv 1410.6483.
More concretely I would like to know the in between steps of the following equation since I don't get how they arrive to that result. Any help would be great:
\begin{equation}
I_\mathcal{C}= \frac{1}{\pi^{2-\epsilon}} \int d^{-2\epsilon} l_\epsilon \frac{\theta((k^+)^2-\vec{k}_\perp^2 - \vec{l}_\epsilon^2)}{\vec{k}_\perp^2 + \vec{l}_\epsilon^2} = \\
\frac{\theta(k^+ - |\vec{k}_\perp|)}{\pi^2\Gamma(-\epsilon)} \int^{(k^+)^2 - \vec{k}_\perp^2}_0 d \vec{l}_\epsilon^2 \frac{1}{(\vec{l}_\epsilon^2)^{1+\epsilon} (\vec{k}_\perp^2 + \vec{l}_\epsilon^2)} 
\end{equation}

where ε arises in the regularization of divergent integrals in dimensional regularization.

After some reading I have seen that one can divide the integrand as:

\begin{equation}
    \int d^{-2\epsilon} = \int d\Omega_{-2\epsilon} \int dl_\epsilon l^{-2\epsilon -1}_\epsilon
\end{equation}

The angular integral in d-dimensions is:
\begin{equation}
    \int d\Omega_d = \frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)}
\end{equation}

Furthermore, $dl_\epsilon^2 = 2l_\epsilon dl_\epsilon$.
With this we get:

\begin{equation}
    I_\mathcal{C} =  \frac{1}{\pi^{2}\Gamma(-\epsilon)}
    \int dl_\epsilon^2 \frac{\theta((k^+)^2 - \vec{l}_\epsilon^2 - \vec{k}_\perp^2)}{(\vec{l}_\epsilon^{2})^{\epsilon + 1} (\vec{k}_\perp^2 + \vec{l}_\epsilon^2)}
\end{equation}

but I still don't get how they go from the integral  with $\theta((k^+)^2 - \vec{l}_\epsilon^2 - \vec{k}_\perp^2)$ to $\theta(k^+ - |\vec{k}_\perp|)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.